# Python Rock, Paper, Scissors putting scissors as an invalid choice

Tags: python

So i wrote my first Rock, Paper, Scissors in Python and it nearly works. The problem is that it sometimes reads "scissors" as an invalid input, which seems to me completely randomly and i dont know what the problem is. Hoping for an easy fix for it. Here's the code:

```
import time
import random
choice_list = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]

def game():
    won = False
    lost = False
    while not won and not lost:
        user = input("Enter your choice from Rock, Paper or Scissors: ")
        user_i = user.lower()
        com_1 = random.choice(choice_list)
        com_choice = com_1.lower()
        if com_choice == user_i:
            print("Draw, try again!")
        elif com_choice == "rock" and user_i == "paper":
            won = True
        elif com_choice == "rock" and user_i == "scissors":
            lost = True
        elif com_choice == "paper" and user_i == "rock":
            lost = True
        elif com_choice == "paper" and user_i == "scissors":
            won = True
        elif com_choice == "scissors" and user_i == "rock":
            won = True
        elif com_choice == "scissors" and user_i == "paper":
            lost = True
        elif user != "scissors" or "paper" or "rock":
            print("Invalid choice, try again...")
    if won:
        print("Congrats you won, the PC chose " + com_1 + "!")
        won = False
    if lost:
        print("You lost, the PC chose " + com_1 + "!")
        lost = False

play_again = "yes"
while play_again.lower() == "yes":
    game()
    play_again = input("Would u like to play again? ")
if play_again.lower() != "yes":
    print("Goodbye!")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Comment: `elif user != "scissors" or "paper" or "rock"` this is wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix:

```
elif user_i not in ("scissors" or "paper" or "rock"):
    print("Invalid choice, try again...")
```

You were using `user` instead of `user_i`. So, when `user` is `Scissors`, the `elif` condition will fail(`"Scissors" != "scissors"`) and return Invalid choice.

Also,
`elif user != "scissors" or "paper" or "rock"` is evaluated as
`elif (user != 'scissors') or 'paper' or 'rock'` which is not exactly what you intend although it doesn't affect your results. Instead, you should write

```
elif user_i not in ("scissors", "paper", "rock"):
```

Actually, you don't even need the last `elif` since you have already checked for all the valid inputs in the previous `if-else` statements.

Comment: Thank you, i guess i just overlooked it, and thanks for telling me about the list!

Answer (score 0):

In your program, when validating input for invalid words, you are using raw input `user`. This could have different case from `user_i = user.lower()`.

Try with the below line:

```
elif ((user_i != "scissors") and (user_i != "paper") and (user_i != "rock")):
    print("Invalid choice, try again...")
```

If still you get issues, pls let us know your input.

Comment: Thank you too, i must have overlooked it!